# How do I graph this data with a simple scatterplot?

Tags: r, scatterplot

My data looks like this:

[image]

I want to see how weight is distributed. How do I do this?

This just gives me a weird line:

`plot(nc['weight'])`

That isn't right. Any suggestions? I just want to see how the data is distributed.[image]

Comment: A scatterplot plots two variables but you only have one. What exactly did you expect to happen here?

Comment: This isn't off topic, as far as I can see.  The problem isn't specific to R or any particular package.

Answer (score 2):

hist(nc['weight'])

will give you a histogram of the values and a look at the distribution.  You can add the parameter breaks=# to control the resolution of the bars

hist(nc['weight'], breaks=50)

Answer (score 2):

Try `plot(density(nc['weight']))` for a density plot. You can also overlay a density plot on top of a histogram that @KirkDCO suggested.

Another possibility is a boxplot.